# Get clicked object from listView onItemClickedListener without position

Tags: android

I want to get clicked object from listView onItemClickedListener without using the position argument . Because I used a Filter for the adapter , so the position wouldn't be the object I want when a filter performed . thank you in advance

Comment: position is always valid in the current state of adapter,  even when filtered by a Filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an **AdapterView.OnItemClickListener**

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

the second paramter used in onItemClick is the view that was clicked.